# Infinite word size abstraction

Tags: java, javadoc

I was reading the java doc of BigInteger, they mentioned "infinite word size abstraction" more than one places. what are they referring to?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are referring to *word* as  *processing unit* for a computer processor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

The *word size* is normally a small number like 32 or 64 bits for a given processor, but `BigInteger` provides an abstraction for *infinite word size*.